# Play OpenShift deployment - sbt using some directories behind the scenes?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, openshift, typesafe-activator

I am trying to deploy my pet Play Framework project to an [OpenShift gear](https://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_user_guide.html#diy-applications) - in a way that the gear itself builds it and runs when a new version is pushed.

I don't have a problem writing the hooks, but when I try to run the activator to build the app (through hooks or ssh similarly) I get an `Error during sbt execution: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory` error.

I figured it was due to the default directories where sbt pulls the libraries from maven, but changing the ivy.home directory (like `./activator -Dsbt.boot.directory=/tmp -Dsbt.ivy.home=/tmp -Divy.home=/tmp`) doesn't seem to make much of a difference:

```
[someproject-nietaki.rhcloud.com abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd]\> cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
[someproject-nietaki.rhcloud.com repo]\> ./activator
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:178)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:91)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
[someproject-nietaki.rhcloud.com repo]\> ./activator -Dsbt.boot.directory=/tmp -Dsbt.ivy.home=/tmp -Divy.home=/tmp
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Update.scala:100)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:279)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$retrieve$1(Launch.scala:149)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$3.apply(Launch.scala:157)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getAppProvider0(Launch.scala:157)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:142)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:178)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:91)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

I don't really know what happens behind the scenes and what causes the errors. I know I could package the app using `activator dist`, push it to cloud and unpack it there, but this solution isn't as elegant as I would like.

All the tutorials I found seem to be out of date, none of them use the activator and I am kind of stuck with it since I want to use the 2.3 version (and it's going to be the default soon anyways)

Comment: You can also use my cartridge for play2 development on Openshift : https://github.com/tyrcho/openshift-cartridge-play2 (it takes into account this issue with the user.home variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is solely based on [lpiepiora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480975/lpiepiora)'s answer but I changed the approach enough to deserve a separate answer.

I didn't want to rewrite the `sbt.boot.properties` file, especially because it might change in future versions of the activator. I didn't want to be forced to maintain it later on. I figured I could just change the value of the `user.home` variable to a "fake home" directory and it seemed to work. I added the `fakehome/` directory (with just a `.gitignore` file in in) to my repo as well. For future reference, here are my openshift action_hooks:

build:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/activator -mem 500 -Duser.home=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/fakehome clean stage
```

start:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/target/universal/stage/bin/my_project -J-Xms128M -J-Xmx500M -Dhttp.address=$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP -Dhttp.port=8080 -Dpidfile.path=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/misc/pid.pid &
```

stop:

```
#!/bin/bash
kill $(cat $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/misc/pid.pid)
rm $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/misc/pid.pid
exit 0
```

The activator seems to work correctly (however slowly) when I use it that way.

The remaining problem is that the build is painfully slow and seems to hit a timeout when I want to compile it on the (small) gear - I'm pretty sure I'm going over the 512MB memory limit. I'll probably try switching to local compilation and deploying the locally compiled files.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure activator to use custom `sbt.boot.properties`, as it is described [in the documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Launcher/GettingStarted.html#running-an-application).

The activator comes with the sbt.boot.properties, so you can use that one as a template.

For example replace all `user.home` with something you can write to, e.g. `openshift.data.dir`.

```
[scala]
  version: 2.10.2

[app]
  org: com.typesafe.activator
  name: activator-launcher
  version: ${activator.version-read(activator.version)[1.1.3]}
  class: activator.ActivatorLauncher
  cross-versioned: false
  components: xsbti

[repositories]
  local
  activator-local: file://${activator.local.repository-${activator.home-${openshift.data.dir}/.activator}/repository}, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  maven-central
  typesafe-releases: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases
  typesafe-ivy-releasez: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]

[boot]
 directory: ${sbt.boot.directory-${sbt.global.base-${openshift.data.dir}/.sbt}/boot/}
 properties: ${activator.boot.properties-${openshift.data.dir}/.activator/version-${activator.launcher.generation-0}.properties}

[ivy]
  ivy-home: ${openshift.data.dir}/.ivy2
  checksums: ${sbt.checksums-sha1,md5}
  override-build-repos: ${sbt.override.build.repos-false}
  repository-config: ${sbt.repository.config-${sbt.global.base-${openshift.data.dir}/.sbt}/repositories}
```

Once you have new `sbt.boot.properties` launch activator like this

```
./activator -Dopenshift.data.dir=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR -Dsbt.boot.properties=/tmp/sbt.boot.properties
```

The activator should use newly created `sbt.boot.properties` and store all its files in the `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`.